Plane/line distance problem: finding a point given equations of plane and line
Here is the question:

The point $Q$ has position vector $(7,4,6)$, the plane $P$ has equation $2x + y + 3z = 36$, and the line $L$ has equation $(20, -8, 1) + t(-7, 5, 3)$.
$Q$ lies in the plane $P$. The point $M$ lies on the normal to $P$ which passes through $Q$, and the point $R$ is the point on $L$ which is closest to $M$. $MQ = MR$. Find the coordinates of $M$.

So far I have tried finding the general equation of $MQ = (7, 4, 6) + s(2, 1, 3)$. Hence $M$ must have general coordinates $(7+2s, 4+s, 6+3s)$. I then defined $R$ as the projection of the direction vector of $L$ onto the vector of $M - (20, -8, 1)$ and tried to find the distance $MR$.
Is there a simpler way to do this? Going through the algebra of finding the projection and then the distances seems both tedious and prone to errors (if not entirely wrong)

I am not able to understand how the projection of $L$ on $M-(20,-8,1)$ gives $R$.

On giving a little thought, it is clear that $R$ is fixed. This stems from the fact that the lines in consideration, i.e., the normal to $P$ through $Q($say $N)$ and $L$, are skew lines whose direction vectors are perpendicular. Using the property of such skew lines

If $2$ skew lines $l$ and $m$ have perpendicular direction vectors and say $|AB|$ is the shortest distance between them, with $A$ lying on $l$ and $B$ lying on $m$, for any point $C$ on $l$, its shortest distance from $m$ will be $|BC|$ and vice versa.

Proof: Let $|CD|$ be the shortest distance between $C$ and $m$ with $D$ on $m$. Consider the plane $\pi$ formed by the lines $l$ and $CD$. Now, note that $m$ is perpendicular to both $l$ and $CD($since $D$ is the point on $m$ closest to $C)$.
Using the property that a line perpendicular to $2$ given lines is a normal to the plane formed by them, we get that $m$ is a normal to $\pi$. So, for any point on $l$, its foot of perpendicular on $m$ will be fixed, viz., the point on $m$ closest to it will be the point of intersection of $\pi$ and $l$, i.e., $D$. But for point $A$, $B$ is such a point on $m$. Hence, $D$ and $B$ coincide.
To find $R$, let its coordinates be $(20-7\lambda, -8+5\lambda, 1+3\lambda)$ and use $\vec{QR}.\vec{L}=0$:
$$(13-7\lambda)(-7)+(-12+5\lambda)(5)+(-5+3\lambda)(3)=0$$
$$\implies\lambda=2$$
$$\implies R\equiv(6,2,7)$$
Now, since $M$ lies on $N$ which is perpendicular to $P$, $MQ=$ distance of $M$ from $P$:
$$MQ=MR$$
$$\require{cancel}\implies\frac{|2(7+2s)+(4+s)+3(6+3s)-36|}{\sqrt{14}}=\sqrt{(2s+1)^2+(s+2)^2+(3s-1)^2}$$
$$\implies\cancel{14s^2}=\cancel{14s^2}+2s+6\tag{beautifully}$$
$$\implies s=-3$$
Therefore, the point $M$ is $(1,1,-3)$.

I take it when you say 'perpendicular skew lines' you mean there is a line through them which is perpendicular to them both?

@Eric yes, I mean their direction vectors are perpendicular.

So if I have two points A and B on the line L1 and two points D and C on L2, and L1 and L2 have a line normal to both of them, then AC, AD, BC, BD are all perpendicular to L1 and L2?

@Eric no no, not at all...how did you infer this? Note that a pair of skew lines always has a line normal to both of them.

Just looked up the internet including MSE and Wikipedia that there exists no such term as 'perpendicular skew lines'. Let me correct the terminology in my answer.

Okay, thanks. But suppose A and B are points on L1 and C and D points on L2 (with L1 and L2 skew perpendicular). |AC| is the shortest distance between the two lines. Is it the case that the lines BC and AD are also perpendicular to L1 and L2?

@Eric $BC$ and $AD$ would be perpendicular to $L_2$ and $L_1$ respectively.

@Eric Kindly consider upvoting and/or accepting my answer if you found it helpful.

Yes, thank you for your response.

I just noticed as well I think M should be (1,1,-3). At least that is what the previous answer (which has disappeared) got (with R the same value).

@Eric oops, that was a typo, fixing it rn.
